# How do I get my Yubikey to work with SSH in Windows 10?

Tags: git, ssh, yubikey

after buying a Yubikey 5 NFC for technical interest (firmware 5.2.7) and setting up FIDO2 authentication where possible, I ran into the problem that I could no longer connect to my GitLab server via SmartGit because the second factor is not requested and therefore I can't connect to the server.

I then decided to deal with it on Windows 10 via Git Bash and SSH. Unfortunately, the documentation here assumes a lot of prior knowledge and I am an absolute beginner on the subject. In the meantime I managed to connect to the server with Git Bash and SSH using a locally generated SSH certificate.

Now I would like to use the Yubikey instead of the certificate stored locally on the computer. Unfortunately, all instructions (e.g. this one https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key-for-a-hardware-security-key) lead to the same error message for me:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "name@mail.com"
Generating public/private ed25519-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Key enrollment failed: invalid format
```

Before that, I am prompted to enter the PIN. The interesting thing: The message looks exactly the same, whether I have inserted the Yubikey or not does not matter. The attempt with ecdsa-sk leads to the same result.

(btw. I have already successfully stored an OpenPGP certificate on the Yubikey.)

Now I also read something about libfido2, however I can't find any instructions on how to use it on Windows 10.

So my question: how do I manage to use my Yubikey instead of my local key?
Or: How do I install libfido2 if this is the problem?

Comment: GitLab 14.8 (Feb. 2022) does support ecdsa-sk now. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67657004/6309).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May 2021

So: it is true [Security keys are now supported for SSH Git operations](https://github.blog/2021-05-10-security-keys-supported-ssh-git-operations/) , as announced early this month (May 2021) on GitHub, but, as [discussed here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27204695&ref=upstract.com&curator=upstract.com&utm_source=upstract.com), there are still issues.

Your error message looks like a bug in progress on Debian: "[issue 980393: `/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk` fails with "Key enrollment failed: invalid format"](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980393)".
And it is [still being reported this month](https://twitter.com/ndm/status/1391915400829411328).

If this fails also with `-t ecdsa`, try and using [a plugin for OpenSSH to connect to FIDO/U2F security keys through native Windows Hello APIs](https://github.com/tavrez/openssh-sk-winhello) might help.
Type `export SSH_SK_HELPER=/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-sk-helper.exe` first, as seen in [`tavrez/openssh-sk-winhello` issue 1](https://github.com/tavrez/openssh-sk-winhello/issues/1).
Check your OpenSSH version is at least 8.2. It is on my side with the latest Git for Windows:

```sh
ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
```

The [OP DroidDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5245525/droiddroid) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639931/how-do-i-get-my-yubikey-to-work-with-ssh-in-windows-10#comment119635748_67657004):

> Nevertheless, I now have the problem that GitLab doesn't support security keys yet: [issue 213259](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/213259)

---

Feb. 2022: those security keys should be supported on GitLab now.

See [GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#support-for-ecdsa-sk-and-ed25519-sk-ssh-keys) (February 2022)

> ### Support for ecdsa-sk and ed25519-sk SSH keys
>
> [OpenSSH 8.2](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html#8.2) added support for FIDO/U2F hardware authenticators with new
> ecdsa-sk and ed25519-sk key types.
>
> GitLab now supports these key types, allowing users to take advantage of hardware-backed SSH authentication.
>
> https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_8/ssh_key.png -- Support for ecdsa-sk and ed25519-sk SSH keys
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#generate-an-ssh-key-pair-for-a-fidou2f-hardware-security-key) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/213259).

Comment: Thank you, I am able to generate the keypair now. In the link you posted someone mentioned he's having this issue using administrator rights. So I started git bash as administrator and this seems to have solved my issue. Never the less I now have the problem that GitLab doesn't support security keys yet ... https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/213259

Comment: @DroidDroid Well done. I will follow the GitLab issue you mention.