# ssh agent plink fails to popup yubikey input form

Tags: git, windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree, plink, yubikey

When using plink as ssh agent in sourcetree under windows to pull code from Linux servers that has Yubikey configured, it just fails to popup yubikey authentication form, so I have no chance to click my yubikey and the pull fails directly.

Is there anyway to enable the popup authentication form for yubikey ?

Comment: Ummmm ... your tags don't make any sense.  To the best of my knowledge there's no `sourcetree` for linux, and if you have `ssh` why do need `plink`?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in "[How do I get my Yubikey to work with SSH in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67657004/6309)", do not use plink (check also your environment variable for any GIT_SSH variable: you should remove them)

Use the openSSH paackage with Git, and use the latest Git (2.33.0.2).
You can test it with a sk file, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646481/6309) (that was for GitHub, but should work with a remote Linux)

Comment: Could you please be more detailed on this ? I am a newbie on this setup .

Comment: @FaceBro First check your environment variables: do you have anything related to ssh? (like GIT_SSH)?